# Python convert list of numpy array to 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is my list of numpy array:

> [array([ 0.33007796,  0.10620873, -0.03484848, -0.168602  ,  0.4564025
>   ,
>           0.11370123, -0.37691383, -0.10863657, -0.16251889,  0.02544368,
>          -0.03327211,  0.23185516, -0.32642304, -0.15969283,  0.45812119,
>           0.24997875,  0.13897375,  0.01468147, -0.15773412, -0.53704494,
>          -0.06121204,  0.19579619,  0.30438485,  0.05908984,  0.29759387,
>          -1.61107886, -0.55878418,  0.06553798,  0.37648846, -0.35247216,
>           3.33212613,  0.22318645, -0.21187862, -0.39089783,  0.05294092,
>          -0.0413471 ,  0.02179677,  0.25394103,  0.01980207, -0.22377998,
>          -0.08718371,  0.02940335,  0.02797039,  0.34935868, -0.05733391,
>           0.07754561, -0.0972822 ,  0.05259355, -0.0562219 ,  0.15573672])
>
> array([ 0.20259871,  0.12458311, -0.20787658, -0.16353745, 
>   0.40842594,
>           0.25567385, -0.2703993 , -0.15097566, -0.13328776, -0.0331789 ,
>           0.02034447,  0.07318579, -0.22284479, -0.19045474,  0.23279801,
>           0.11366921,  0.11914298, -0.09647366, -0.20951753, -0.22698855,
>          -0.045307  ,  0.11098107,  0.0524313 , -0.0424848 ,  0.11007177,
>          -1.51343118, -0.36741486, -0.05812052,  0.13435007, -0.09786326,
>           2.84255649,  0.00325309, -0.27484909, -0.47422259, -0.03957974,
>          -0.13663797, -0.03203189,  0.0155929 , -0.06982855, -0.08388657,
>          -0.16572997,  0.04573543, -0.00667479,  0.21973781, -0.14895521,
>           0.1210014 , -0.21911705, -0.05924631, -0.07265716, -0.10153842])]

However I want this:

> [[ 0.33007796,  0.10620873, -0.03484848, -0.168602  ,  0.4564025
>   ,
>           0.11370123, -0.37691383, -0.10863657, -0.16251889,  0.02544368,
>          -0.03327211,  0.23185516, -0.32642304, -0.15969283,  0.45812119,
>           0.24997875,  0.13897375,  0.01468147, -0.15773412, -0.53704494,
>          -0.06121204,  0.19579619,  0.30438485,  0.05908984,  0.29759387,
>          -1.61107886, -0.55878418,  0.06553798,  0.37648846, -0.35247216,
>           3.33212613,  0.22318645, -0.21187862, -0.39089783,  0.05294092,
>          -0.0413471 ,  0.02179677,  0.25394103,  0.01980207, -0.22377998,
>          -0.08718371,  0.02940335,  0.02797039,  0.34935868, -0.05733391,
>           0.07754561, -0.0972822 ,  0.05259355, -0.0562219 ,  0.15573672]
>
> [ 0.20259871,  0.12458311, -0.20787658, -0.16353745, 
>   0.40842594,
>           0.25567385, -0.2703993 , -0.15097566, -0.13328776, -0.0331789 ,
>           0.02034447,  0.07318579, -0.22284479, -0.19045474,  0.23279801,
>           0.11366921,  0.11914298, -0.09647366, -0.20951753, -0.22698855,
>          -0.045307  ,  0.11098107,  0.0524313 , -0.0424848 ,  0.11007177,
>          -1.51343118, -0.36741486, -0.05812052,  0.13435007, -0.09786326,
>           2.84255649,  0.00325309, -0.27484909, -0.47422259, -0.03957974,
>          -0.13663797, -0.03203189,  0.0155929 , -0.06982855, -0.08388657,
>          -0.16572997,  0.04573543, -0.00667479,  0.21973781, -0.14895521,
>           0.1210014 , -0.21911705, -0.05924631, -0.07265716, -0.10153842]]

What I tried:

```
X_transform = [list(x) for x in X_transform]
```

But it unfortunately throws: `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`

I also tried `X_transform.tolist()` it gives(Not quite what I want):

> [array([ 0.33007796,  0.10620873, -0.03484848, -0.168602  ,  0.4564025
>   ,
>           0.11370123, -0.37691383, -0.10863657, -0.16251889,  0.02544368,
>          -0.03327211,  0.23185516, -0.32642304, -0.15969283,  0.45812119,
>           0.24997875,  0.13897375,  0.01468147, -0.15773412, -0.53704494,
>          -0.06121204,  0.19579619,  0.30438485,  0.05908984,  0.29759387,
>          -1.61107886, -0.55878418,  0.06553798,  0.37648846, -0.35247216,
>           3.33212613,  0.22318645, -0.21187862, -0.39089783,  0.05294092,
>          -0.0413471 ,  0.02179677,  0.25394103,  0.01980207, -0.22377998,
>          -0.08718371,  0.02940335,  0.02797039,  0.34935868, -0.05733391,
>           0.07754561, -0.0972822 ,  0.05259355, -0.0562219 ,  0.15573672]),
>
> array([ 0.20259871,  0.12458311, -0.20787658, -0.16353745, 
>   0.40842594,
>           0.25567385, -0.2703993 , -0.15097566, -0.13328776, -0.0331789 ,
>           0.02034447,  0.07318579, -0.22284479, -0.19045474,  0.23279801,
>           0.11366921,  0.11914298, -0.09647366, -0.20951753, -0.22698855,
>          -0.045307  ,  0.11098107,  0.0524313 , -0.0424848 ,  0.11007177,
>          -1.51343118, -0.36741486, -0.05812052,  0.13435007, -0.09786326,
>           2.84255649,  0.00325309, -0.27484909, -0.47422259, -0.03957974,
>          -0.13663797, -0.03203189,  0.0155929 , -0.06982855, -0.08388657,
>          -0.16572997,  0.04573543, -0.00667479,  0.21973781, -0.14895521,
>           0.1210014 , -0.21911705, -0.05924631, -0.07265716, -0.10153842])]

I also tried:

```
a = []
for i in range(1000):
    a.append([X_transform[i][0]])
```

But it throws `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

Finally I tried:

```
X_transform = np.stack(X_transform)
```

It throws: `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`

Comment: If all the arrays in the list have the same shape, then `stack` will work.  But since they differ, it's impossible to create a 2d array from them.  I'd advise checking the shapes, `[a.shape for a in yourlist]` to see which differ.  Is that difference intentional, or an accident.

Comment: Thanks one element in an array was a nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you ask for, but let's try [iPython]:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: a = np.stack([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([11,12,13])])
   ...: print a.shape
   ...: print a
   ...: 
(2, 3)
[[ 1  2  3]
 [11 12 13]]
```

Comment: Actually I tried np.stack, it didn't work either. Please see my edited question. Thanks

Comment: This solution works in my hands given the list of two arrays you provide.

Comment: Thank you one element in an array was a nan. It worked after I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `np.asarray()`

Here's an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(6) + 10
>>> a
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
>>> b = np.arange(6) + 20
>>> b
array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25])
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> c
[array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]), array([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25])]
>>> e = np.asarray(c)
>>> e
array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us define `u` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
u = [np.array(range(24)),np.array(range(24))]
u
>>>[array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])]
```

I would then use `list comprehension` to convert u to a list of list as follows.

```
v = [val.tolist() for val in u]

print(v)

>>> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you're saying you have a list

```
l  = [np.array([ 0.33007796, 0.10620873, -0.03484848, -0.168602 , 0.4564025 , 0.11370123, -0.37691383, -0.10863657, -0.16251889, 0.02544368, -0.03327211, 0.23185516, -0.32642304, -0.15969283, 0.45812119, 0.24997875, 0.13897375, 0.01468147, -0.15773412, -0.53704494, -0.06121204, 0.19579619, 0.30438485, 0.05908984, 0.29759387, -1.61107886, -0.55878418, 0.06553798, 0.37648846, -0.35247216, 3.33212613, 0.22318645, -0.21187862, -0.39089783, 0.05294092, -0.0413471 , 0.02179677, 0.25394103, 0.01980207, -0.22377998, -0.08718371, 0.02940335, 0.02797039, 0.34935868, -0.05733391, 0.07754561, -0.0972822 , 0.05259355, -0.0562219 , 0.15573672]),
      np.array([ 0.20259871, 0.12458311, -0.20787658, -0.16353745, 0.40842594, 0.25567385, -0.2703993 , -0.15097566, -0.13328776, -0.0331789 , 0.02034447, 0.07318579, -0.22284479, -0.19045474, 0.23279801, 0.11366921, 0.11914298, -0.09647366, -0.20951753, -0.22698855, -0.045307 , 0.11098107, 0.0524313 , -0.0424848 , 0.11007177, -1.51343118, -0.36741486, -0.05812052, 0.13435007, -0.09786326, 2.84255649, 0.00325309, -0.27484909, -0.47422259, -0.03957974, -0.13663797, -0.03203189, 0.0155929 , -0.06982855, -0.08388657, -0.16572997, 0.04573543, -0.00667479, 0.21973781, -0.14895521, 0.1210014 , -0.21911705, -0.05924631, -0.07265716, -0.10153842])]
```

Then this should convert it to the format you want :

```
new_l = [list(i) for i in l]
```

I think that what you're doing wrong is that `X_transform` is not the full list, but only one of the numpy arrays inside the list, so its elements are floats, not numpy arrays, hence the error raised.